# What are the requirement for smooth voice chat with Skype?

Tags: internet, skype, chat, latency, voice

In our country, Internet is very expensive. In comparison to that, I have a fair Internet connection. However, I experience choppy sound, lagging, etc. when making voice calls using Skype.

I use a linux machine. I close all other browser activities, chat and run only skype voice. In my bandwidth monitor, I see about 128 kilobits per second is used. Thats 16KB/sec. However I have  128KB/sec connection. It's a direct fibre to home connection. Latency to google is 90ms during skype voice, much less other times.

What could be the problem? Isn't this internet connection adequate? Note the fibre connection is directly inserted to my LAN card via ONU, no other devices in the middle.

Comment: You will want to post more information about your Internet connection. Try speedtest.net. What is your upload speed? Download speed? Latency? Latency is incredibly important here; 90ms to google is terrible. Skype recommends 100kbps upload and download (https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1417/how-much-bandwidth-does-skype-need), but really should specify latency requirements, too.

Comment: what's your downloading speed?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton the connection is 1024kbps. 90ms to google is while in skype voice.  Skype consumes only 128kbps.

Comment: @Harikrishnan I get 1024kbps while downloading. Uploading is same too.